# What are the specific requirements for libpcap directional capture support?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, sniffing, pcap

I'm using libpcap on Linux to capture network traffic from a wireless adapter (2.4 GHz). The `pcap_setdirection` seems to allow you to setup the capture device so that it ignores traffic originating from the device, but I get an error when I try to set it to return incoming traffic only.

My libpcap version appears to be 1.9.1, so directional capture should be supported. I know wired Ethernet has transmit and receive lines, which could be used to distinguish outgoing data from incoming data, but I'm not sure if WiFi adapters have a way to determine which device the traffic came from (self v. others).

Are there any special hardware or kernel requirements for restricting the traffic direction with libpcap (no-WiFi, kernel settings, adapter support, etc.)?

Comment: Note that libpcap captures packets from the kernel, _before_ they reach the hardware – so it absolutely does not care whether the physical link has separate wires or not. (Gigabit Ethernet doesn't.)

Comment: @user1686 I had no idea the wires in Gigabit Ethernet were bidirectional, that's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [email chain](https://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2006-February/000681.html), it should work with any device supporting monitor mode on Linux and BSD as long as the library is recent enough.

I was getting an error because unlike every other configuration call, `pcap_setdirection` only works after the capture handle has been activated.